# Count returns Zero asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, filter

I have a table which contains regions, districts, complaints and case status. What I want to do is :

- create 3 instances of the table
- use one as the primary table where each district is used to compare the other 2
- one table will count all complaints per district that match the primary instance
  -the third to count all case status and then insert all three results into another table

This is the code so far. Problem is the count always returns a 0 which throws an error.

```
foreach (DataRow mainrow in CaseTable.Rows)
{
    RegionName = mainrow.Field<string>("Region");
    DistrictName = mainrow.Field<string>("DistrictName");

    if (mainrow.Field<string>("CaseStatus") == "Resolved")
        DistrictcaseCount++;
    DistrictcaseCount++;
    PercentageResolved = (DistrictResolvedCount / DistrictResolvedCount) * 100;
    PercResolved = PercentageResolved.ToString() + "%";

    ReportTable.Rows.Add(RegionName, DistrictName, DistrictcaseCount, DistrictResolvedCount, PercResolved);
}
```

Comment: just glancing at your code, i can tell you if you divide a variable by itself it will always be 1, so percentageResolved will always be 100

Comment: @Dom not when that value is 0, then you get the "throws an error" that OP refers to.

Comment: When calculating PercentageResolved, shouldn't you be dividing by DistrictcaseCount ?

Comment: DistrictResolvedCount isn't defined in this method, so it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be multiple problems with the snippet of code in your question.

1. You are incrementing `DistrictcaseCount` instead of `DistrictResolvedCount`
2. You are calculating the percentage by dividing `DistrictResolvedCount` by itself.
3. Your are performing a division, that for `DistrictResolvedCount / DistrictcaseCount`, will always be 0 because they are integers.
4. You are adding a new row after each case.

I believe this will do what you intended:

```
// This will count cases and resolved cases, grouped by district.
var districtGroups = 
    from row in CaseTable.Rows
    group row by new { 
        Region = row.Field<string>("Region"), 
        District = row.Field<string>("DistrictName") 
    } into g
    select new {
        Region = g.Key.Region,
        District = g.Key.District,
        CaseCount = g.Count(),
        ResolvedCaseCount = g.Count(r => "Resolved".Equals(r.Field<string>("CaseStatus")))
    };

// this will calculate the percentage and add the rows.
foreach (var entry in districtGroups)
{
    // determine percentage.
    string percentageResolved;
    if (entry.CaseCount > 0)
    {
        var percent = (100.0 * entry.ResolvedCaseCount) / CaseCount;
        percentageResolved = percent.ToString() + "%";
    }
    else // What to do if there are no cases? 
    {
        percentageResolved = "N/A";
    }

    // add row for the district.
    ReportTable.Rows.Add(
        entry.Region, entry.District, 
        entry.CaseCount, entry.ResolvedCaseCount, 
        percentageResolved);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw my mistake and rectified it. I got the count but the percentage was still 0. I will try this code. it looks beautiful. I'm such a noob. Thanks guys

Comment: I am still having trouble with your code. First is the CaseTable.Rows.AsEnumerable(). I changed it to CaseTable.AsEnumberable() which didn't generate an error. The other error i can't seem to rectify is the: ResolvedCaseCount = g.Count(r => "Resolved".Equals(e.Field<string>("CaseStatus"))). The error comes from e. Please help

Comment: @Yaw ok fixed it, I removed the `AsEnumerable()` part and replaced the `e` with `r`.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex I fixed the issues. Thank you so much for the code. I ended up with this:

var districtGroups = from row in CaseTable.Rows.Cast() 
group row by new
            {
                Region = row.Field("Region"),
                District = row.Field("DistrictName")
            } into g
            select new
            {
                Region = g.Key.Region,
                District = g.Key.District,
                CaseCount = g.Count(),
                ResolvedCaseCount = g.Count(r => "Resolved".Equals(r.Field("CaseStatus")))
            };

```
        // this will calculate the percentage and add the rows.
        foreach (var entry in districtGroups)
        {
            // determine percentage.
            string percentageResolved;
            if (entry.CaseCount > 0)
            {

                var percent = (100.0 * entry.ResolvedCaseCount) / entry.CaseCount;
                percentageResolved = percent.ToString() + "%";
            }
            else // What to do if there are no cases? 
            {
                percentageResolved = "N/A";
            }

            // add row for the district.
            ReportTable.Rows.Add(
                entry.Region, entry.District,
                entry.CaseCount, entry.ResolvedCaseCount,
                percentageResolved);
        }
```